# mssql large data field not showing in php

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I am using mssql server backend and news field having huge data on that but when i am retrieving this info in php then it shows me only limited part not all info on that field

here is my php code-

```
$result_subset = mssql_query ("Select news as notes from atimo_m12 where name like 'masses%' and category = 'M-Offices & Ministries'");

while($rsSelection = mssql_fetch_assoc($result_subset)){  
    echo $rsSelection["notes"];     
}
```

Comment: @doublesharp - not solve still

Comment: Please see my answer with more detailed explanation. What is the size of the data your are trying to return?

Comment: Which OS do you use - Windows or something else? Have you checked the driver settings?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this link helps: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php#64470
Have a look at the limits in php.ini:

mssql.textlimit = 16384
mssql.textsize = 16384

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to set a value for `mssql.textlimit` and `mssql.textsize` in your `php.ini` file. If these values are missing, the default value will be `4096` bytes and result in your data being truncated in PHP. The maximum value you can set is `2147483647` bytes - this value being 2GB in bytes, which may result in memory issues on your server. You should set this to be higher than the maximum data size you need to support

```
; Valid range 0 - 2147483647.  Default = 4096.
mssql.textlimit = 2147483647

; Valid range 0 - 2147483647.  Default = 4096.
mssql.textsize = 2147483647
```